# Error running Django project in virtualenv

Tags: python, django

I have a django project which works fine without virtualenv. But now I'm putting it in a virtualenv and it doesn't run.
Without virtualenv:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=Janta.settings.local
```

This works fine.
With virtualenv when I do the same as above I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/moni/.virtualenvs/janta_proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/moni/.virtualenvs/janta_proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/moni/.virtualenvs/janta_proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/home/moni/.virtualenvs/janta_proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/mon/.virtualenvs/janta_proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/mon/.virtualenvs/janta_proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/moni/.virtualenvs/janta_proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'Janta.settings.local' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named celery
```

This is what comes when I try installing celery in the virtualenv:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Celery in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>dev in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Celery)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): billiard>=3.3.0.13,<3.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Celery)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): kombu>=3.0.8,<4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Celery)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): anyjson>=0.3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from kombu>=3.0.8,<4.0->Celery)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): amqp>=1.4.0,<2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from kombu>=3.0.8,<4.0->Celery)
Cleaning up..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Enter the virtualenv, type `pip freeze | grep celery` and edit the answer to your question. Seems like there's no celery in your virtualenv. And if you can't find celery, run `pip install celery`.

Comment: i tried installing it using pip in the virtualenv but it says its installed already. And when i pip freeze in te virtualenv, its not there

Comment: Are you running your `pip` or `virtualenv` commands using sudo?

Comment: that's your problem. I've added an answer, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sudo` will force everything to install globally, and virtualenv is *the solution* to that problem. It allows you to create virtual environments which have their own independently installed packages, so you can avoid having everything installed globally.

Recreate the virtualenv, install all of your needed packages using `pip install packagename` and you should be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

See the last line of the output: You're somehow celery somewhere, which appears not to be installed in your virtualenv.

Comment: i tried installing it using pip in the virtualenv but it says its installed already. And when i pip freeze in te virtualenv, its not there.